# PHP Same Timezone Different Mins in Both Servers

Tags: php

I have 2 servers in which i have the below code in a test script

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set( "Europe/Athens" );
echo "TimeZone: " . date_default_timezone_get();
echo "<br />Current Time: " . date("Y-m-d H:i:s",time());  
?>
```

I uploaded this script in both servers, i run at exactly the same time And the Response was:

### SERVER 1

```
TimeZone: Europe/Athens
Current Time: 2014-11-28 19:27:19
```

### SERVER 2

```
TimeZone: Europe/Athens
Current Time: 2014-11-28 19:21:08
```

You will notice the seconds/mins are not the same.

Why?

Comment: Are these on the same physical hardware? Are the server's clocks synchronised to anything?

Comment: Because the time comes from the server, not PHP? Have you checked the time on those servers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system clocks are set at different times, that's all - at least one of them is inaccurate. Presumably one or both of them isn't synchronized. Ideally, you should synchronize against something like NTP.

This isn't something you would do in your PHP code - it's likely to be a matter of asking server administrator.

In other words, your *code* is fine, and this is a matter for administration. It's *highly* unlikely that this is a discrepancy in time zone information.

Comment: But... i am the server administrator :D . How can i synchronize them properly with a command or sometihng?

Comment: @BlackDream: That's hard to answer as we don't know *anything* about the servers - not even their operating system. At this point it's a question for ServerFault really... do some research first (searching for ntp and your operating system name is likely to be enough, to be honest) and then ask on ServerFault if you need to. Server administration itself is off-topic here.

Comment: is your server based on linux ?

Comment: if is based on a linux : `/usr/sbin/ntpdate -u 0.rhel.pool.ntp.org` this should work. you can make a cron job too if you want to update your time every half hour exmp: `*/30 * * * * /usr/sbin/ntpdate -u 0.rhel.pool.ntp.org`